# "Count cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: java, variables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZEm5.png)

I am unable to resolve this error plz help me out? What to do? how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You need **count** to be a global variable

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and especially you shouldn't post code as an image. Code fragments should be included as text so everybody can copy and paste it to their own IDE.

Answer (score 0):

count is declared inside the scope of the loop, so it is not accessible by the outside.
you need to declare it as a local variable (in the scope of the entire class).

Comment: These is no *global variable* concept, as such, in Java. Method variables are *local variables* and class variables have different visibility, depending on their access modifiers.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thank You so much.